how can i fix the display in Msg3 here in my code?
I don't know what should I change here in the code
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    Msg1 DB 'Enter first number: $'
    Msg2 DB 10, 13, 'Enter second number: $'
    Msg3 DB 10, 13, 'Entered numbers are: $'
    PositiveMsg DB ' is positive$'
    NegativeMsg DB ' is negative$'
    Comma DB ', $'
    NewLine DB 10, 13, '$'
    InputBuffer DB 6 DUP('$')

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Display message asking for the first number
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Msg1
    int 21h

    ; Read the first character from the user
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov bl, al           ; Save the first character
    cmp al, '-'          ; Check if the first character is '-'
    je ReadFirstNegative
    sub al, '0'          ; Convert ASCII character to its corresponding numeric value
    jmp FirstNumberProcessed

ReadFirstNegative:
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'          ; Convert ASCII character to its corresponding numeric value
    neg al               ; Negate the value to make it negative

FirstNumberProcessed:
    mov bh, al           ; Move the numeric value of the first number to BH

    ; Display message asking for the second number
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Msg2
    int 21h

    ; Read the second character from the user
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    mov bl, al           ; Save the first character
    cmp al, '-'          ; Check if the first character is '-'
    je ReadSecondNegative
    sub al, '0'          ; Convert ASCII character to its corresponding numeric value
    jmp SecondNumberProcessed

ReadSecondNegative:
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, '0'          ; Convert ASCII character to its corresponding numeric value
    neg al               ; Negate the value to make it negative

SecondNumberProcessed:
    mov dh, al           ; Move the numeric value of the second number to DH

    ; Display message indicating the entered numbers
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Msg3
    int 21h

    ; Display the first entered number
    mov al, bh           ; Move the numeric value of the first number to AL
    add al, '0'          ; Convert numeric value to its corresponding ASCII character
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

    ; Determine if the first number is positive or negative
    mov ah, 09h
    cmp bh, 0
    jge FirstPositive
    lea dx, NegativeMsg
    int 21h
    jmp CheckSecondNumber
FirstPositive:
    lea dx, PositiveMsg
    int 21h

CheckSecondNumber:
    ; Display a comma and space
    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx, Comma
    int 21h

    ; Display the second entered number
    mov al, dh           ; Move the numeric value of the second number to AL
    add al, '0'          ; Convert numeric value to its corresponding ASCII character
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

    ; Determine if the second number is positive or negative
    mov ah, 09h
    cmp dh, 0
    jge SecondPositive
    lea dx, NegativeMsg
    int 21h
    jmp ExitProgram
SecondPositive:
    lea dx, PositiveMsg
    int 21h

ExitProgram:
    ; Exit program
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h
main endp

end main

here in Msg3 the output is wrong
It should determine what number i will input in Msg1 or Msg2. It should be "1 is positive, -2 is negative"

The task was already solved in my answer at Input and output of signed single-digit decimal numbers.
I'm even tempted to think that you read it before seeing your definition of Comma DB ', $' as was suggested by me.
Then why does your code fail? Well, just like it was with the other asker, you also forget that DH is not an independent register at all. DH is the name we give to the high 8 bits of the 16-bit register DX. You are using both these registers at the same time but for different purposes. That's a no-go! In my answer to the other question I have put one of the numbers in the BH register and the other number in the BL register. That's a good solution.
Additionally you don't even try to output the minus character in your final summarizing message. Again, find out by studying the answer at Input and output of signed single-digit decimal numbers.

Problem 1: Not printing the correct number.
When you read the number, if the user enters a '-' first, you negate the value of al after converting from ASCII and store that in bh / dh. So bh / dh hold a positive OR negative number.
When you try to print it out, you are simply converting to ASCII, without looking at the sign. Thus, -2 + '0' won't generate '2' (I'm surprised it doesn't generate '.', to be honest).
You've also forgotten that you may need to print out a '-' before you print the digit.
Problem 2: Always saying positive.
I believe this is because of cmp bh, 0. Since a negated byte is simply one with the high bit set (-2 = 11111110, for example), cmp may be mistakenly seeing that as 254 - and so it's always greater than 0 and jge always redirects. It's supposed to be a signed subtraction, but that may only work properly on the full ebx and edx registers. My assembler is a bit rusty.
I leave it to you to find a way to test that top bit, to decide if it's negative. You may want to always keep the positive value in bh / dh and use some other way to remember if the first and second numbers were negative - it would simplify the rest.

"cmp may be mistakenly seeing that as 254 - and so it's always greater than 0 and jge always redirects." This is incorrect, cmp bh, 0 then jge will only jump if the signed 8-bit value is >= 0.

@ecm: OK, fair enough. I'm baffled, then, as to why it is failing in that respect since dh should be negative. A slight change of strategy should address the OP's problem anyway.
